# Regex/Python - why is non capturing group captured in this case?

Tags: python, regex

Each element of this raw data array is parsed by regex

```
['\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', 
 'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday:', 
 ' 12:00 pm to 03:30 pm & 07:00 pm to 12:00 am\t\t\t\t\t',      
 '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', 
 'Sunday:', 
 ' 12:00 pm to 03:30 pm & 07:00 pm to 12:30 am\t\t\t\t\t']
```

This is my regex `(\\r|\\n|\\t)|(?:\D)(\:)`

https://regex101.com/r/fV7wI2/1

[image]

Please note that I'm trying to match the `:` after Saturday but not the `:` in Time formats eg `12:00`

Although the above image classifies capturing/non capturing groups properly

on running `re.sub("(\\r|\\n|\\t)|(?:\D)(\:)",'',"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday:")`

returns

`'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturda'` (missing 'y' after saturday)

instead of

`'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday'`

why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a look-behind instead of a non-capturing group if you want to check a substring for presence/absence, but exclude it from the match:

```
import re
s = "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday:"
print(re.sub(r"[\r\n\t]|(?<!\d):",'',s))
#                         ^^^^^^^ 
# Result: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/UX5SNx)

Here, `(?<!\d)` only checks if the preceding character before a colon is not a digit.

Also, alternation involves additional overhead, character class `[\r\n\t]` is preferable, and you do not need any capturing groups (round brackets) since you are not using them at all.

Also, please note that the regex is initialized with a raw string literal to avoid overescaping.

Some [more details from Python *Regular Expression Syntax*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) regarding *non-capturing groups* and *negative look-behinds*:

> `(?<!...)`
>    - Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for `...`. This is called a **negative lookbehind assertion**. Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length and shouldn’t contain group references. Patterns which start with negative lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the string being searched.
>
> `(?:...)`
>   - A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

As look-behinds are *zero-width assertions* (=expressions returning *true* or *false* without moving the index any further in the string), they are exactly what you need in this case where you want to *check* but not *match*. A non-capturing group will consume part of the string and thus will be part of the match.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the term "non-capturing". It just means it won't make a separate captured group for the subtext matched with the group, but the subtext will still be part of the match. I have updated my answer and refined the regex pattern. Please check and let me know if you need more clarifications. I guess [*Lookarounds Stand their Ground*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground) is a must-read for you.

Answer (score 1):

`\D` is non digit.In `saturday` `y` is `non digit` so it is being deleted.

Use

```
print re.sub("(\\r|\\n|\\t)|(?<=\D):",'',"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday:")
```

Using `lookahead` will ensure you dont deleted extra characters before `:`/

Comment: `y` is `non digit` However its a non-capturing group `(?:\D)`, why would it be matched?

Comment: @wolfgang it is not capturing mean it will not from `group` and it will not be stored in `\1`.Captruing or non captruing it iwll always be matched

Comment: @wolfgang `capturing` is not capture match by regex but capture groups by regex.it will just enable disable groups

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood that `(?:\D)` will not considering as 1 letter in `Regex`, in actually it's wrong, it just doesn't capture `\D` into variable `$1`. every times you use `(...)`, you have to realize that any pattern inside `(...)` will be captured into variable either `$1`, `$2`, ... in Regex.

The best way to deal with this problem is using positive/negative look ahead as answer from @vks and @stribizhev because lookaround is just an assertion which not consume any letter, this is why we call them the **"zero width assertion"**.